# Поиск по <select>

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, как можно обойти все `<option>` в `<select>`'e найти тот, который совпадает с определенным текстом, и узнать его `.val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на jQuery:

```js
$('select').find('option').each(function() {
  if ( $(this).text() == 'Два' ) {
    document.write( $(this).val() );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="One">Один</option>
  <option value="Two">Два</option>
  <option value="Three">Три</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Взять `<select>`, взять все `<option>` в нём, по очереди сравнить их текстовое содержимое (`.textContent`) с заданным текстом и вывести значение (`.value`) нужного:

```js
var text = "two";
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var options = select.options;
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].textContent == text) {
     console.log(options[i].value);
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option value="first">one</option>
    <option value="second">two</option>
    <option value="third">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно выбрать все `option`, например с помощью [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Пробежаться по ним в цикле, сравнивая текст проверяемого элемента с нужным

Получить значение найденного элемента.

Например:

```js
document.write(
  [].find.call(document.querySelectorAll('#select option'), function(el) {
    return el.text == 'Text3'
  }).value
);
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="value1">Text1</option>
  <option value="value2">Text2</option>
  <option value="value3">Text3</option>
  <option value="value4">Text4</option>
  <option value="value5">Text5</option>
  <option value="value6">Text6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let inp = document.querySelector('.inp');

 let option = document.getElementsByTagName('option');


 inp.addEventListener('keyup', function (e){ let val = e.target.value;
 //тут ловим каждый вводимый символ

 for (let elem of option) {   if (elem.textContent.includes(val)) {
 //если в тексте option есть то что мы вводим то выбираем его
     elem.selected = true;   } } });

 нативный js
```